# WOL - Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Power computer off, computer turns back on

Tags: 12.04, power-management

I have an GA-B75M-D3H Gigabyte motherboard with an i3 processor that I'm using WOL from a windows machine to start the computer. The WOL is working fine but the issue is when I power the computer off, whether from command line or from the GUI the computer waits 6 seconds and then turns itself back on. If I let it boot up and then shut it off a second time it will stay off for good.

I am wondering if there is something I need to alter in my init.d to keep this from happening or if it's just the nature of my motherboard? Has anyone else had this issue? I know my computer supports WOL but I can't figure out why it keeps turning back on after powering it down. Rather frustrating. Any help would be great!

Comment: My Satellite L850 with Ubuntu 13.10 seems to do this also.

Answer (score 0):

Is WOL in the BIOS or in the Ubuntu install itself? If it is in the BIOS, certain BIOS's have an option to restart when shut off in this mode, like a server would act to keep online 24/7. This may be an option within your BIOS, check around in there for a setting that restarts your computer after a power down or something along those lines. I hope it leads you in the right direction.. Hope I was of help.

Comment: I combed through the BIOS and found one setting that restarts the computer if power is lost to it, but that option was already disabled. One thing I tested was when shutting the computer down I unplugged the ethernet cable and the computer still turned itself back on after power down. So I don't think it's a WOL magic packet that is starting the computer back up.